# InfoPath/Workflow error: A button in the form template is missing an xd:CtrlID attribute?

Tags: workflow, infopath

I have a list with a custom InfoPath form. There is a workflow tied to the list which, in turn, starts an approval workflow, then sets fields when the approval workflow completes.

I have full control to the site. When I start the workflow with myself as the approver, I can approve it and everything works correctly. When I specify a coworker as the approver (who also has full control), they get the email through outlook as usual. When they click on "Open this Task" and try to click on "Approve" (or any other option), they get the error:

> Outlook cannot complete this action, because of an error in the form's
>   code. A button in the form template is missing an xd:CtrlID attribute.

I am not using any custom code in the form. Anyone have any idea what is going on?

SharePoint 2013, SharePoint Designer 2013, InfoPath Designer 2013, Outlook 2010

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem,
There are a couple fixes, if you are using workflow 2013 then you can enable InfoPath custom forms in central admin (the exact steps are escaping me as I have just done that on our dev site so far)
If you are using 2010 workflows (I assume this would work for 2013 workflows as well) the work around is to use explorer mode to find the workflows folder, click your specific workflow, edit the xml, such that it no longer requires the buttons that you deleted on your form. Save then run it should run fine, this xml tells the program that it needs the default buttons, note that every couple if publishes you will have to edit the xml as it is regenerated.

Comment: I'm using a 2010 workflow. What in the XML do I have to remove? Do you have a code sample?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug here is the fix given by Microsoft

1. Exit Outlook.
2. Start Registry Editor. To do this, use one of the following procedures, as appropriate for your version of Windows.
3. Windows 10, Windows 8.1, and Windows 8: Press Windows Key + R to open a Run dialog box. Type regedit.exe, and then press OK.
4. Windows 7: Click Start, type regedit.exe in the search box, and then press Enter.
5. In Registry Editor, locate and click the following subkeys, depending on the bitness of your Windows and Outlook installations.
6. **For Windows 32-bit running Outlook 32-bit or Windows 64-bit running Outlook 64-bit:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\

F**or Windows 64-bit running Outlook 32-bit:**

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\
Locate and right-click the following value, and then click Rename:

7. OUTLOOK.exe
   Enter the name of OUTLOOK.exe.bak, and then press Enter. Exit Registry Editor.

[Microsoft Issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3124629/in-outlook--buttons-in-workflow-forms-are-not-clickable-or-display-an)